# Realizar varias operaciones con interfaz entre assembler y C

Tags: c

Estoy tratando de realizar diferentes operaciones con assember para unidad FPU de los procesadores Intel , en medio de una interfaz con C.

Las operaciones a realizar son:

```html
43.001 * 0.00751
0.00000001 * 1.4142135623730951
0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 − 0.3
```

```html
/* Este es el código de prueba: */

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
double r;
double s;
const double a = 1;
const double b = 0.1;
const double c = 43.001; 
const double d = 0.00751;
const double e = 0.00000001; 
const double f = 1.4142135623730951; 
const double g = 0.3; 

__asm__ ("fldl %1;" //cargo a
  "fldl %2;"  //cargo b
  "fldl %3;"  //cargo c
  "fldl %4;"  //cargo d
  "faddp;"   // suma a con b y lo guarda en st(0)
  "fmul st2,st3" // c*d y lo guarda en st(2)
  "fstl %0;" : "=m" (r) : "m" (a), "m" (b)
  "fstl %1;" : "=m" (s) : "m" (c), "m" (d)   
  );

printf("%.16e\n", r);
printf("%.16e\n", s); 
return 0;
}
```

La idea es que el resultado de cada operación quede almacenado en una posición del stack, pero no lo he logrado hacer porque no estpy seguro de si la sintaxis de por ejemplo fmul st2,st3 es correcta. ¿Cómo se almacena cada operación en un a posoción del stack para después imprimir sus resultados?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que resolví el problema.

Escribí el siguiente código para realizar las operaciones:

```html
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
double result_mult1;
double result_mult2;
double result_resta;
const double a = 43.001;
const double b = 0.00751;
const double c = 0.00000001; 
const double d = 1.4142135623730951;
const double e = 0.1;
const double f = e+e+e; 
const double g = 0.3;

__asm__ ("fldl %1;" //Carga a
   "fldl %2;" //Carga b
   "fmulp;"
   "fstl %0;" : "=m" (result_mult1) : "m" (a), "m" (b) );
   
__asm__ ("fldl %1;" //Carga c
   "fldl %2;" //Carga d
   "fmulp;"
   "fstl %0;" : "=m" (result_mult2) : "m" (c), "m" (d) );
   
__asm__("fldl %1;" //Carga g
  "fldl %2;" //Carga f
  "fsubp;"   //Resta g con f y lo guarda en st(0)
  "fstl %0;" : "=m" (result_resta) : "m" (g), "m" (f)); 

printf("%.16e\n", result_mult1);
printf("%.16e\n", result_mult2);
printf("%.16e\n", result_resta);
return 0;
}
```